# Why React.memo fails to memoize this component?

Tags: reactjs, memo

I have two components, one receiving another one as a prop. For clarity I will remove all the unnecessary logic and JSX:

```
function Child() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Child rerender");
  });
  return <div>Child component</div>;
}

function Parent({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Parent rerender");
  });
  return (
    <div>
      Parent component
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

They're both memoized as follows:

```
const ChildMemo = React.memo(Child);
const ParentMemo = React.memo(Parent);
```

Now, they're both being rendered in the top level component with a state, again for clarity's sake let's imagine for now it's just a button setting some state:

```
function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("App rerender");
  });
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Update state {count}</button>
      <ParentMemo>
        <ChildMemo />
      </ParentMemo>
    </>
  );
};
```

I expect that clicking a button triggers state update leading to just "App rerender" being logged in the console. Yet the `<Parent />` component is being rerendered as well. Why does that happen?

Comment: @Adnan then why are ChildMemo isn't rerendered?

Comment: because it doesn't have any property or state, so there is no change that makes it rerender. But ParentMemo has children, so it will always rerender because react doesn't know if you're putting the state in children or not. 

Add any property or children to ChildMemo, even without using the prop of child, you should see it rerender.

Comment: you do see it's wrapped in React.memo() call, do you? And quoting [the docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/memo) "memo lets you skip re-rendering a component when its props are unchanged." <ParentMemo /> have one single prop: <ChildMemo/> which itself is memoized. So it doesn't change.

Answer (score -1):

**FIRST**

Looking at your code, you're using `useEffect` without deps array.

So the `parent rerendered` message you see in the console is not because it's rerendered, but because you didn't define dependencies array;

so every time:

a state changes -> the `ParentMemo` is executed -> the effect will run -> message is printed to console,

but it doesn't mean it's rerendered.

If you want to know if it's rerendered, you must add empty dependencies array:

```js
useEffect(()=>{console.log("component executed and will compare with shadow-dom to check if it needs rerender")});
useEffect(()=>{console.log("created and rerendered")},[]);
useEffect(()=>{console.log("created or updated, and rerendered"},[state]);
```

Without the array, `useEffect` have nothing to compare, so it will assume that you intentionally need to run this effect with every `execution`.

**SECOND**

Since `ChildMemo` don't have any state and **no props are changed**, so there is **no need to rerender it**, so `ChildMemo` is not executed again.

But `ParentMemo` has `children` prop, so you can't guarantee it will not be rerendered.

To quote from the [Docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/memo#reference):

"Wrap a component in **memo** to get a memoized version of that component. This memoized version of your component will **usually not be re-rendered** when **its parent component** is re-rendered as long as **its props have not changed**. ((****But****)) **React may still re-render it**: memoization is a performance optimization, **not a guarantee**."

To avoid `ParentMemo` re-execution, you can do an ugly solution, which is to pass `ChildMemo` as it's as children:

```
function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("App rerender");
  });
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Update state {count}</button>
      <ParentMemo>
        {ChildMemo}
      </ParentMemo>
    </>
  );
};
```

and call it from inside `ParentMemo`:

```
function Parent({ children: C }: { children: React.ReactNode | () => React.ReactNode }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Parent rerender");
  });
  return (
    <div>
      Parent component
      {typeof C === "function" ? <C /> : C}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: 1) You're basically coming from a false assumption that "the 'parent rerendered' message you see in the console is not because it's rerendered, but because you didn't define dependencies array". As I have already told you in the comment to the question itself, [according to docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#parameters) "If you omit dependencies argument, your Effect will re-run after every re-render of the component." So, yeah that DOES mean it's rerendered. 2) You seem to lack understanding of what rerendering is. Calling (executing, as you put it) ParentMemo IS rerendering.

Comment: 3) "If you want to know if it's rerendered, you must add empty dependencies array:" - nothing can be far more from truth, than this statement. I have to refer to docs (which you, apparently, don't bother to) [again](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#passing-an-empty-dependency-array) - If your Effect truly doesn’t use any reactive values, it will only run after the INITIAL RENDER. So it will run only once. I'm still struggling to understand why do you bother answering pretty complex question regarding memoization, when you have very little understanding of how React rendering works.

Comment: @tnsaturday Forget about `useEffect`. You're main issue is that ParentMemo is re-rendered and writes to console everytime the state changes even though it's memoized and has nothing to do with the state. Again, because you're using JSX Children, you can't guarantee it's not going to rerender. Pass the function ChildMemo as children, not the rendered ChildMemo, this should make you avoid the rerender because when it compares the props, it will find that it's the same function.